# centos 6 debuginfo repository does not have httpd debug version available

Tags: centos, redhat, httpd, debugging, gdb

I am trying to get the debug version of httpd so I can use it in conjunction with gdb. I am having a hard time getting them, and they don't seem to be in the standard epel-debuginfo repository. What should I do?

```
> [root@buildbox-rhel6 ~]# debuginfo-install httpd
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
enabling epel-debuginfo
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel-debuginfo/metalink                                                                              | 8.3 kB     00:00     
 * base: mirrors.cicku.me
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * epel-debuginfo: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirrors.arpnetworks.com
 * updates: linux.mirrors.es.net
epel-debuginfo                                                                                       | 3.1 kB     00:00     
epel-debuginfo/primary_db                                                                            | 487 kB     00:01     
Checking for new repos for mirrors
Could not find debuginfo for main pkg: httpd-2.2.15-15.el6.centos.1.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package apr-1.3.9-5.el6_2.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package apr-util-1.3.9-3.el6_0.1.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package db4-4.7.25-17.el6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package expat-2.0.1-11.el6_2.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package openldap-2.4.23-26.el6_3.2.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package openldap-2.4.23-26.el6_3.2.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package pcre-7.8-4.el6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package glibc-2.12-1.80.el6_3.6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6.x86_64
Could not find debuginfo pkg for dependency package zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.x86_64
No debuginfo packages available to install
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like [debuginfo-install](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/YumUtils/DebugInfoInstall) is only searching epel-debuginfo. httpd in not in EPEL. The httpd debuginfo is in a repo called '[debug](http://debuginfo.centos.org/6/x86_64/)'.

Enable debug repo:

```
debuginfo-install --enablerepo=debug httpd
```

If that doesn't work use yum:

```
yum --nogpgcheck --enablerepo=debug install httpd-debuginfo
```